# When using late-bound enumerated type is the only option to use the numeric representation of the type

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ado

Using late bound `ADO` code from within a `VBA` script I've got the following:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim cm As Object
Dim rs As Object

    'get in touch with the server
    'Create ado objects.
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 0

Set cm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cm.CommandText = "xxx.dbo.xxxStoredProcName"
Set cm.ActiveConnection = cn

cm.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
```

I can see that `rs` is a recordset object from the line `Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` but without the comment ('`adCmdStoredProc`) I'd be struggling to remember what `cm.CommandType = 4` meant.

Is there a way to change this code so that I can stick with late binding but use the descriptive form of the enumerated type `CommandTypeEnum` rather than the numeric form?

Comment: Yes. Declare this at the top `Const adCmdStoredProc = 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the declarations section of a standard module

```
Enum adCommandTypeEnum
    adCmdUnspecified = -1
    adCmdText = 1
    adCmdTable = 2
    adCmdStoredProc = 4
    adCmdUnknown = 8
    adCmdFile = 256
    adCmdTableDirect = 512
End Enum
```

And it will work just like if you early bound. If you go back to early binding, make sure you delete this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx